Possible to set Request Headers in Selenium?
I'm trying to write a test against a site that authenticate's by checking some headers.
In other frameworks it's possible to add headers to the driver but I can't see anything like that in Selenium.
Is there a way to add request headers to selenium webdriver? Ideally on a per-test case so the existing suite doesn't have to use headers it doesn't need.

What framework have you tried? What request are you sending with Selenium? Selenium is a browser automation tool. If you can access the site using a browser, then it should be accessible using Selenium. If you are sending HTTP requests, then selenium is not the tool.

Why not use basic HttpClient
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.14</version>
</dependency>


or you can use RestTemplate or WebClient depending upon your requirement.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


Since you are trying to setup headers, you are not testing UI but rather your endpoints.
Selenium is not supposed to be used like this.
Selenium automates actions by a user in browser. Since user doesn't/cannot specify header, you shouldn't try that either.
